# Add item to cart in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Want to add plus and minus buttons after clicking plus icon on the green button. And then the cart icon appears. Here is my code for the button I was created with a plus icon. How do I improve my code in order to get the below result?

[image]

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(320, 160, 0, 0),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 80,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: const CircleBorder(),
              primary: Color(0xffA3DD45),
              minimumSize: const Size(60, 60)),
          child: const Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`AnimatedSwitcher`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) and use `Positioned` widget inside `Stack`.

```dart
 int itemCount = 0;

  Widget child1() => ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            itemCount++;
          });
        },
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: const CircleBorder(),
          primary: const Color(0xffA3DD45),
          minimumSize: const Size(60, 60),
        ),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
      );

......

Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 80,
        child: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          child: itemCount <= 0 ? child1() : child2(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```